# Entity Framework 6 - Save Changes

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to perform an insert with EF 6.

I have verified I have a connection to the database, because I can do a read:

```
List<Driver> drivers = DataContext.Drivers.ToList();
```

With a sql profiler, I can see this do a select on the database, and it returns an item I manually inserted.

I am trying to perform an insert like this:

```
var driver = new Driver();
driver.DriverName = "Blah";
DataContext.Drivers.Add(driver);
DataContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges(); //false
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

except nothing is inserted, and the changetracker seems to show that it has not detected any changes. I also saw suggestions to use `.Attach` but this had the same results.

Any help on what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

---

(MyEntities.Context.cs)

```
 public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyEntities()
            : base("name=MyEntities")
        {
        }
```

---

```
public partial class MyDataContext : MyEntities
    {
```

---

```
public class SqlDataService : DataServiceBase<...Data.MyDataContext>
    {

//where I am trying to do the insert with the code above
```

**edit:** No not using code first (not that i'm aware of!) not sure if the above code samples help, but show how I have set up my classes

Comment: Do you use code first? If so please provide your Context-Class

Comment: What else do you do in `MyDataContext`? Normally, adding an item to a `DbSet` should cause a change in the change tracker. It looks like other modifications you did prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have AutomaticTrackChanges turned off somewhere in your code.
Try adding this line before the addition:

```
var driver = new Driver();
driver.DriverName = "Blah";
//Turning Automatic changes tracking on:
DataContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
DataContext.Drivers.Add(driver);
DataContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges(); //True
DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Note:** `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is usually turned off for performance considerations